# how to toggle ng-class when directive ng-repeat item is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, ng-class

I have created a plunker with my current code .. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hWy6WGbSymL0YIzt1Ti2?p=preview)

When one of the buttons on each item is clicked i want that 'li' element to get the class selected (thats is have its background changed to grey. and if another element is clicked i want the previous items selected class to be removed and added to the clicked item. so basically a toggle of the class.. )

I have already tried to achieve it by using the $index :

```
    $scope.isClicked = function(index){
             $scope.selected = index;
           };
```

and in the items.tpl.html toggle it :

```
 <li class="item" ng-class"{selected: index===selected}">
```

what am i doing wrong here? Can someone please help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See forked [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eMusdtB8TLaoG5BtJP7x?p=preview)

In a nutshell, you're are using `ng-repeat` for the directive `user-group-item`. For each repeated `user-group-item` (2 in this case), the directive will make its own scope and controller method initialization. So you can not use `$scope.selected` inside the directive to store what is selected, because each `user-group-item` will have its own `selected` variable in its `$scope`

You need to store that selected state outside the directive, ie in the main controller. I created a function `setSelected` in the main controller and passed it as a method reference using `&` in the directive. Inside the `$scope.isClicked` method, you need to refer to the parent scope to get the function `setSelected`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get why it wasnt working.. now the code is working .. however initially the class is added as well when the page first loads.. is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: never mind that was just simple . changed the initial value of $scope.selected to -1 instead of 0 :)

Comment: @Y.Hewa glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

You're close ... you should move the function that gets called on ng-click into your list controller - that way you can set the "selected" index and inject that in all your list entries ...

Here's an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XgMjxBAa6nxqry3Rtt9a?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('userGroupList', function($scope) {
    $scope.groups = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "group 1",
      description: "this is group 1"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "group 2",
      description: "this is group 2"
    }];
    $scope.selectedIdx = -1;
    $scope.clickFn = function(index) {
      console.log('click ' + index)
      $scope.selectedIdx = index;
    }
  })
  .directive('userGroupItem', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        group: '=',
        index: '@',
        clickFn: '&',
        selectedIdx: '='

      },
      templateUrl: 'items.tpl.html',
      controller: function($scope) { }
    };
  })
```

and then you inject selectedIdx:

```
<div>
   <ul class="row">
      <user-group-item group="group" ng-repeat="group in groups" index="{{$index}}" selected-idx="selectedIdx" click-fn='clickFn($index)'></user-group-item>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot this helped mee! now my codes working.. now the class is applied to the first element when the page is loaded.. i only want the class added when the button is clicked. Is there anyway to remove it ?

Comment: if you set the selectedIdx to -1 it won't find an id and do exactly what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

In your directive...

```
$scope.selected = false;

$scope.isClicked = function(){
    $scope.selected = true;
};
```

Then in your html...

```
<li class="item" ng-class"{'selected' : selected}" ng-click="isClicked()">
```

Just run the function `$scope.isClicked` via the `ng-click` directive, then when that item is clicked, the function will fire, and update the `selected` value to `true`, adding the class `selected` to your `<li>`.

Comment: yup it works now. but is there anyway to toggle it so that when i click another button the class is removed from the previous element and added to the current element?